# ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I was trying to configure my Django project to deploy to Heroku. I am getting the following error and I don't really know how to fix it.

Here is the **full traceback** and error:

```
22:46:15 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
22:46:15 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
22:46:15 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
22:46:15 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
22:46:15 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
22:46:15 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
22:46:15 web.1  |     __import__(module)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/nirla/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from dj_static import Cling
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler as DebugHandler
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 8, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 13, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.views import static
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 96, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     template_translatable = ugettext_noop("Index of %(directory)s")
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 65, in gettext_noop
22:46:15 web.1  |     return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
22:46:15 web.1  |     if settings.USE_I18N:
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
22:46:15 web.1  |     self._setup(name)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
22:46:15 web.1  |     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
22:46:15 web.1  | ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Here is my **wsgi.py** file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "nirla.settings") #nirla is the name of the project


application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

And in case it was relevant, my **manage.py** file:

```
import os
import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "nirla.settings")
    
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Can anyone seem to understand the issue here? And if so, can you be so kind as to explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I figured that the **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** had to be set some way, so I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) (link updated) and found:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Though that is not enough if you are running a server on heroku, you need to specify it there, too. Like this:

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings --account <your account name>
```

In my specific case I ran these two and everything worked out:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=nirla.settings
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=nirla.settings --account personal
```

---

**Edit**

I would also like to point out that you have to re-do this every time you close or restart your virtual environment. Instead, you should automate the process by going to venv/bin/activate and adding the line: `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` to the bottom of the code. From now on every time you activate the virtual environment, you will be using that app's settings.

Comment: So `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "nirla.settings")` is ignored?

Comment: Related article https://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Answer (score 115):

From [*The Definitive Guide to Django: Web Development Done Right*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gpr7J7-FFmwC&lpg=PA42&ots=_vTIfpKGYF&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> If you’ve used Python before, you may be wondering why we’re running `python manage.py shell` instead of just `python`. Both commands will start the interactive interpreter, but the `manage.py shell` command has one key difference: before starting the interpreter, it tells Django which settings file to use.

Use Case: Many parts of Django, including the template system, rely on your settings, and you won’t be able to use them unless the framework knows which settings to use.

> If you’re curious, here’s how it works behind the scenes. Django looks for an environment variable called `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, which should be set to the import path of your settings.py. For example, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` might be set to `'mysite.settings'`, assuming mysite is on your Python path.
>
> When you run `python manage.py shell`, the command takes care of setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` for you.**

Comment: Thanks for that. Though the django shell threw the same error, I eventually solved that.

I am in a particular case, in which I do not have a `settings.py` file/module in my code base, but a `settings` package/folder. This package contains an `__init__.py` file with all the conventional stuff of the `settings.py`, and other local settings files, imported in __init__.

So I had to config as follows:
`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myappfolder.settings.__init__`

Comment: Thanks, your comment is illuminating. I am developing an app in Django and I developed a .py script to upload data from an excel sheet into the model. At the beginning of my settings.py I added the two lines you suggested, that is "from django.conf import settings", "settings.configure()".. But as I run it, my console returns “django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet”, and I can't understand why. Here is my script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305225/django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet-when-trying

Answer (score 74):

Django needs your application-specific settings. Since it is already inside your `manage.py`, just use that. The faster, but perhaps temporary, solution is:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed when I was going through the [Django 2.0 Tutorial - Part 5 - Automated testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial05/). Previously, I entered Python interactive mode within my environment by typing `python` alone. This would lead to an AppRegistryNotReady exception after typing `from polls.models import Question`.

Comment: thanks, I thought `django-admin shell` is same as `python manage.py shell` but they are different.

Answer (score 57):

In my case it was the use of the `call_command` module that posed a problem.
I added `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` but it didn't work.

I finally found it:

add these lines at the top of the script, and the order matters.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.management import call_command
```

Comment: in which file to add these lines?

Comment: On the scrip you going to execute

Comment: I think there is no need to add last line `from django.core.management import call_command` .

Comment: I add these line on the top of manage.py, and it works.

Comment: Amazing. This allows me to create fake data very easily, from a .py script. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you are here due to error while trying to run daphne on server then here is the answer for you .

Change you asgi.py file like this.

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import url

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mc_backend.settings')

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack   
import api_backend.routing


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            api_backend.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

Comment: it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_backend'

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped and fixed my issue, I have created a custom token auth middleware for Django channels and because of which the issue was caused while running daphne, with your solution i rearranged the code and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it was a Python path issue.

1. First set `your PYTHONPATH`
2. then set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`
3. then run `django-admin` shell command (`django-admin dbshell`)

```
(venv) shakeel@workstation:~/project_path$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/shakeel/project_path
(venv) shakeel@workstation:~/project_path$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings
(venv) shakeel@workstation:~/project_path$ django-admin dbshell
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

otherwise `python manage.py shell` works like charm.

Answer (score 6):

I've got this error while trying to import models from python console. My workaround:

```py
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
django.setup()
```

> `my_app.settings` is path to your `settings.py`

And then you can import your models:

```py
from users.models import UserModel
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a *.env* file that will hold your credentials at the root of your project and leave it out of versioning:

```
$ echo ".env" >> .gitignore
```

In the .env file, add the variables (adapt them according to your installation):

```
$ echo "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.production"> .env
#50 caracter random key
$ echo "SECRET_KEY='####'">> .env
```

To use them, put this on top of your production.py settings file:

```
import os

env = os.environ.copy()
SECRET_KEY = env['SECRET_KEY']
```

Publish it to Heroku using this gem: http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config.git

```
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config.git
$ heroku config:push
```

This way you avoid to change virtualenv files.

*Based on this [tutorial](https://wagtail.io/blog/deploying-wagtail-heroku/)

Comment: Warning: config:push is not a heroku command.
Did you mean config:add? [y/n]: y
 !    Usage: heroku config:set KEY1=VALUE1 [KEY2=VALUE2 ...]
 !    Must specify KEY and VALUE to set.

Answer (score 3):

I have used **pipenv** to manage virtual environment for django project.

**SOLUTION**

```
1. pipenv shell
2. python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the local server, run Django shell using `python manage.py shell`. It will take you to the Django python environment and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had a wrong way of import.

First I imported models of django without (before I declare that the file use django)

```py
import pika, json, os, django
from products.models import Product

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()
```

But then I changed the import as below and it works (basically declaring file uses django and then importing models and other apps)

```py
import pika, json, os, django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()

from products.models import Product
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I ran tests using pytest and poetry.
I solved the problem using these steps:

1. You need to install this package: `pytest-django`
2. Go to `pyproject.toml` file or create `pytest.ini` file
3. Then add this code to `pyproject.toml`  => `[tool.pytest.ini_options]`

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "your_project_name.settings"
```

Refer - [pytest-django doc](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when I set in admin.py my `list_display = ('name',)` I changed it to `list_display = ('name','date')` And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just had to introduce the missing variables through `"Preferences" => "Terminal" => "Environment variables"`:

1. Go to `Preferences (cmd +,)`
2. Go to `Terminal` and add two Environment
   variables (PYTHONPATH and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)

`PYTHONPATH` pointed to the absolute path of the project root.
`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointed to the settings file name (relative to the root path and without `.py`)

See the attached picture, please!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Settings.py file probably located at projects\projects folder, and Add your Apps name like below example:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',

```
'django.contrib.auth',

'django.contrib.contenttypes',

'django.contrib.sessions',

'django.contrib.messages',

'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'YourAppsName'
```

Answer (score 0):

correct command **python manage.py runserver**
when i tried **Django-admin runserver** i got the above error. Later realized my mistake

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to configure Django settings is to specify them when running `manage.py` commands:

Example:

```
python manage.py test $(MODULE) --settings=$(SETTINGS)
```

And then remove this line from your `manage.py` script: `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'nirla.settings')`

This will tell Django to run tests on `$MODULE` module, using the indicated `$SETTINGS` settings file.

In this case `$SETTINGS` could be something like `nirla.settings`.

Of course, this is valid only if running the Django app using the `manage.py` script.

If you for example want to run the system through something else, for example `UWSGI`, then you will need to specify to `UWSGI` which setting file to use.

Example:

- `USGI` service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI django service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/your_service_name/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /opt/your_service_name/your_service_name.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the `/opt/your_service_name/your_service_name.ini` file should be something like:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /opt/your_service_name

# env variables
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_service_name.settings.production
env = STATIC_ROOT=/opt/your_service_name/var/static
env = MEDIA_ROOT=/opt/your_service_name/var/media

module = your_service_name.wsgi:application

# env dir config
home = /opt/powerlex/env

socket = /tmp/socket
master = true
workers = 2
chmod-socket=666

# if app not found uwsgi is not starting
need-app = True
```

As you can see at this line `env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_service_name.settings.production` we configure the settings to be used

PS: the above UWSGI configuration is just an example, so we don't expect it to work as it is.

Answer (score -1):

i found it! 
for **windows users** instead of commanding `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_project.settings` after everytime you activate your virtual environment 
add the following code section

```
$env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "your_project.settings"
```

in your `Activate.ps1` file, after below code section

```
# Now set the environment variable VIRTUAL_ENV, used by many tools to determine
# that there is an activated venv.
$env:VIRTUAL_ENV = $VenvDir
```

like:

```
# ...
# Now set the environment variable VIRTUAL_ENV, used by many tools to determine
# that there is an activated venv.
$env:VIRTUAL_ENV = $VenvDir

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable
$env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "your_project.settings"

# ...
```

`your_project` is your Project Name where the `settings.py` file is inside it.

Answer (score -2):

> if running a python script in the build file other than manage.py file
> is causing the problem,

**Try installing django-extensions.**

Then, add it to the *INSTALLED APPS*.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django_extensions',
...
]
```

- Make a directory at the root level (manage.py level) named scripts.
- create an **init**.py to make it a python package.
- create the script you want, inside that folder.
- Define a function named run() as it will be excecuted.
- say for example, the script file name is script1.py,then
- run - python manage.py runscript script1
- This will excecute the script.

Include the command in build.sh

For detailed explanation
[django-extensions doc](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html)