# Accessing relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: django, django-models, pycharm, python-import, valueerror

i have searched across stackoverflow and i havent been able to come up with an answer.

I have this directory:

```
project/
    util/
        utility.py
    models.py
```

So here is a description of what each file does

`models.py` :
contains a list of my django models

```
utility.py:
from ..models import *
[...]
```

May i know why i keep getting this error:
`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`?

And how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There reason is that you are trying to import from `non-package` directory. That is, `project` folder is not a package as it does not have `init.py`. That's why, you are getting this error.

Try this:

```
from project.models import *
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it threw me a django.core.exception: InproperlyConfigered

Comment: @AKJ is `project` a Django app or a project root? If it is a project root, why is `models.py` there? It should be inside an app.

Comment: It is the django app

Comment: @AKJ why is there no `init.py`?

Comment: Under the util folder? There is. My project is a lot more than what i gave above. However my models.py is a file so there is no __init__.py

Comment: @AKJ no, under the `project` folder.

Comment: There is one there

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by following the solution posted by this user:

[Django exception : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137339/django-exception-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured)

Go upvote his post if it helped you!