# How to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings? Time to give up with this?? :(

Tags: python, mysql, django, data-science

I am really with Django and I am getting a little bit crazy with this issue. I created a new project and app in Django, run server without problems, but if I ran :

```
django-admin check
```

Im gettin this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LANGUAGE_CODE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I tried to solve with different solutions proposed but none of them worked (probably bad execution by me, IDK). I really hope you can help me, guys!

Thanks in advance,

Best.

Example of similar error than mine, that I took from here [ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

The answer proposed is: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` I tried `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` with my app name instead of "mysite" in my app folder but it does not work...

```
22:46:15 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
22:46:15 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
22:46:15 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
22:46:15 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
22:46:15 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
22:46:15 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
22:46:15 web.1  |     __import__(module)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/nirla/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from dj_static import Cling
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler as DebugHandler
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 8, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 13, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     from django.views import static
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 96, in <module>
22:46:15 web.1  |     template_translatable = ugettext_noop("Index of %(directory)s")
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 65, in gettext_noop
22:46:15 web.1  |     return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
22:46:15 web.1  |     if settings.USE_I18N:
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
22:46:15 web.1  |     self._setup(name)
22:46:15 web.1  |   File "/Users/nir/nirla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
22:46:15 web.1  |     % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
22:46:15 web.1  | ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

Comment: Don't run `django-admin check`, run `python manage.py check`.

Comment: Yeah, that works, I guess I will use the python manage.py shell in order to avoid the error