# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, django-settings

**Background:**

I am working on a microservices project that consists of two apps: `Django app(admin app)` and `Flask app(main app)`. Each of these runs on a `Docker` container.
The error occurred as I was trying to implement a functionality that whenever a product is liked in the main app, the information is passed on to the admin app via `RabbitMQ`, so that the likes could also get updated in its database.

I keep getting this error in the admin app, because of which the likes are not updated in the database of the admin app.

**Project structure of Django (Admin) app**

It consists of one app - Products.

[image: Django app structure]

**Error details:**

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

[image: Error screenshot]

**Relevant files:**

Here is the `consumer.py` file of the admin app.

```
from products.models import Product
import pika
import json
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()

params = pika.URLParameters(
    'amqps://mynfehiw:zXmApSaqRu8AJo3oTmJTxGzzEo8KTs6F@lionfish.rmq.cloudamqp.com/mynfehiw')


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='admin')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print('Received in admin')
    id = json.loads(body)
    print(id)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    product.likes = product.likes + 1
    product.save()
    print('Product likes increased!')


channel.basic_consume(
    queue='admin', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print('Started Consuming')

channel.start_consuming()

channel.close()
```

Here is the `manage.py` file in the admin app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'admin.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the `wsgi.py` file in the admin app:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'admin.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is the `settings.py` file in admin:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'h_j39)qml90o2ir!fo(h2w_4&3$_cy=)7ak2at=d6yo(st9png'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'products'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'admin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'admin.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'admin',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

**Things already tried:**

1. After reading the other answers on StackOverflow, I included this piece of code:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()
```

in the `consumer.py` file. However, this does not seem to work.

2. I ran my Docker container using `docker compose up` and wrote this command on the other terminal.

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=admin.settings
```

This does not work either.

Could you give any idea on how to resolve this error?

Comment: do you have a `settings.py` in your `admin` folder?

Comment: @SLDem yes, I have added the ```settings.py``` file in the question itself.

Comment: have a look at this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set

Comment: @SLDem This is the first link I visited. I have already tried the approaches mentioned here, even wrote about a few of them in my post. They do not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import `Product` after setting up django:

```python
import pika
import json
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "admin.settings")
django.setup()

from products.models import Product

...
```

When you import modules in python their code gets executed: imports are perfomed, classes and variables are defined, etc. Django project files like `models` usually import some django modules which try to read settings when used. And it's not initialized at the moment!

So you need to initialize django first, then import models.