# Probkem in Django with runserver command

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, web-deployment

I started a project in django and everything was okay, but i closed my project and fews days later i tried to reopen, but this error appeared when i put the command "django-admin runserver" :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\moren\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\moren\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\moren\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 67, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

And when i put "python manage.py runserver" this appear :

```
c:\users\moren\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

if anyone can help me I would be very grateful

Comment: Maybe you forgot to activate the virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO\_SETTINGS\_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cd into your project and run the command again, so in short the command `python manage.py runserver` should be executed where the module "manage.py" is located.

Comment: I thing i made it, but can you give me an example about how i can do this?

Comment: What do you mean ? Did you activate your virtual environnement ?