# Python cleaning text emoji-library django-error

Tags: python, django, data-cleaning

I want to use the emoji library to replace emoji's in text, nothing fancy.

```
import os
import django
import emoji
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
django.setup()

test = "This is a teststring  test test :-)  "
message_without_emoji = emoji.demojize(test)
print(message_without_emoji)
```

When I run this code I get an error.  I can't figure out why and how to correct this (never used django).

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMOJI_IMG_TAG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I tried installing django (like suggested), but I still get the error.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FvIa4BADvA

I don't understand why I should install django.  In the documentation it isn't mentioned and the examples are straightforward.
https://pypi.org/project/emoji/

==> Solution
I installed django-emoji and not the emoji library.  I'm using PyCharm and in the menu "Show Context Actions" django-emoji was suggested as first in the list.
I did pip uninstall django-emoji and pip install emoji.
And now it works fine.

Comment: `You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings` this says exactly what you have to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO\_SETTINGS\_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

Comment: Solved: 
pip uninstall django-emoji 
pip install emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==> Solution I installed django-emoji and not the emoji library. I'm using PyCharm and in the menu "Show Context Actions" django-emoji was suggested as first in the list.
I did pip uninstall django-emoji and pip install emoji. And now it works fine.