# How to know which extension is chaning the code in VSCode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I have this code in VSCode:

```
import django
from models import Product
```

The problem is that when I save the file, VSCode change the code (somehow trying to beautify it):

```
from models import Product
import django
```

I had this Prettier extension, and I disabled it, but I still got the problem.

Comment: @SunderamDubey No. It changes the order of the lines. I need to import my model after importing django, but VSCode keeps changing the line order.

Comment: Looks like `isort`: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No it is not. I have not installed `isort`.

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi But why are you importing Django itself at first?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In a Django project, I am trying to run a script that adds data to the database. I got this problem (check the link), and changing the order of imports solved my problem. But now, I don't know why VSCode keeps changing the line order.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225919/2558241

Comment: in this module it does not matter in what order you import, you have to `import django` too in the `models.py` file

Comment: disable all your extensions and try again

Comment: @rioV8 I have tried both of your suggestions, and yet, VSCode continues changing the line order! About your first suggestion, I don't know the reason, but the order matters, because it used to work when it was in the correct order.

Comment: search your settings GUI for `format` and see if there is still a formatter active, formatters are bound by languageID

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah. I just turned off the `file formatter on save` and it worked.

Comment: @JialeDu Sure. I was going to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off all the related extensions, but it didn't work.

SOLUTION:

In the end, what worked for me was to turn the `Format On Save` off.
In VSCode: `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Formatting.`

Here turn the `Format On Save` off.