# Django doesn't import UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

I try to import `UserCreationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`.

However I got an error like this:

`ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

What does this mean?

I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set). However in my wsgi.py file this kind of settings were set up.

What should I do?

UPDATE:

The same error raises when I try to run this code:
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`
`from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager`.

This is my `settings.py` file:

```
"""   
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

```
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "trade_app.apps.TradeAppConfig"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "trade_app.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "markowitz.wsgi.application"


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "database",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "password",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432"
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True
   
STATIC_URL = "static/"

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

Here is the screenshot of my project structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emWbb.png)

Comment: share your `settings.py` with us.

Comment: Is it development error, or in deploy. If development could you share where you try to import

Comment: @JavohirElmurodov It is a development error. I created in my main working directory file `forms.py`. In that file I tried to import.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here

```py
ROOT_URLCONF = "trade_app.urls"
```

Change it to

```py
ROOT_URLCONF = "markowitz.urls"
```

The `ROOT_URLCONF` should be linked to the project urls, not to the app

Comment: If this isn't the case, consider sharing your project directory structure

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Share your project structure if you want a help

Comment: could you tell me how to share the structure?

Comment: @AdilMohak He added "trade_app.apps.TradeAppConfig" to installed apps. It's obviously not the name of the whole project.

Comment: @DavidBidzhoian just make a picture of your folder tree. Usually on the left in your code editor.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Yes but at the same time, the `ROOT_URLCONF = "trade_app.urls"` makes me think `trade_app` is the project name, anyway it's better to share a screenshot of project structure

Comment: @AdilMohak that's very reasonable. However, according to SO rules you should not post answer if you are guessing, the best option is to comment directly under the question.

Comment: @DavidBidzhoian have you tried changing `ROOT_URLCONF = "trade_app.urls"` to `ROOT_URLCONF = "markowitz.urls"`